# What's the word for two events or people that happen in the same place but at different points in history, similar to contemporary?

Tags: single-word-requests

The exact situation I'm trying to fill is with Nathaniel Hawthorne, who lived in Salem, Massachusetts in the 1800's, but wrote a book about the Salem Witch Trials in the 1600's. I want to contrast this word with "contemporary", if such a word exists.

Comment: I'm thinking "co-locational" but that doesn't appear to be a word in this context.

Comment: [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/co-location#:~:targetText=to%20locate%20or%20be%20located,to%20share%20the%20same%20place.) allows the verb colocate and the noun colocation, but doesn't mention the expected adjectival form ?colocational?. This has a niche usage; perhaps OED 'licenses' a more general usage. However, this wouldn't guarantee the advisability of using a word/sense disregarded by the usual reputable online dictionaries.

Comment: You could treat it as ‘local’ history.  That is the usual word.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for "collocal". I actually did not know this was already a word but I had a hunch and searched it.

collocal

adjective

Of, from or in the same place as another

https://www.wordnik.com/words/collocal